# Check if error bag of input array has a particular index

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

**Version of Laravel: 5.5.***

Form

```
<input name="name[]"/>
<input name="name[]"/>
<input name="name[]"/>
```

Validation is put in an error bag.

If I have an error on the second input, I will get an array of error messages with

```
name.1 => "error message"
```

What I want to do is check if the bag has any error for the index name.**i**

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the error at the index **i** with

```
$errors->bagname->has('*.i')
```